# Make a file bigger with truncate in bash

Tags: bash

I have a text file which weights a certain amount of bytes.

To test my file system, I need to programatically make the file 4096 bytes bigger from a bash script.

I am under the impression that this is doable using the `truncate` command, but I cannot figure out how - typing `truncate myfile.txt -s 4096` will leave me with a 4096 bytes file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me something like this is working:

```
truncate -s +4096 myfile.txt
```

this appends 4069 bytes to the given file. I think you miss the plus sign.

Answer (score 2):

`truncate` is useful because appending bytes can't shrink a file. However, *growing* a file is as simple as

```
printf '%4096s' >> myfile.txt
```

which adds 4096 space characters to the end of the file.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the difference. Could you explain it using other words?

Comment: There is nothing I can write to a 10-byte file what will make it *smaller* than 10 bytes, but writing *some* number of bytes to the end of a file will make it bigger. Here, `printf` is simply writing 4096 characters to standard output, which is redirected to the target file (opened in append mode, so they are all written to the end of the existing file instead of overwriting anything that is already there).